# Negating Callback Function Return Value

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

**Straightforward question:**

Can I negate a callback function that returns `true` or `false` o an array.filter() statement? e.g.

```
//the callback function
function isEven(element, index, array){
    if (index%2 == 0 || index == 0){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

//what i want to do with that function
//arr[i] is a string
var evens = arr[i].split("").filter(isEven); //works
var odds = arr[i].split("").filter(!isEven); // doesn't work
```

the above line gives me the error `TypeError: false is not a function`

**Question with some background:**

I'm taking on some Hackerrank challenges and i've come across an exercise that requires to take a string and process it, so the output is: The characters with even index values make a new string and the characters in odd index positions make another string , 0 counts as even.

**Input**

```
airplane
```

**Output**

```
evens = 'arln'

odds = 'ipae'
```

I have already solved it by looping through the string, evaluating the index and then pushing the value to the correspondent new array (which i later convert to a string), but it has occurred to me i could be done in a more functional way, using the `Array.prototype.filter()` function.

now I create a new function that evaluates whether the index number is even or not, and I'd like to use that same function to fill both arrays (evens and odds), like this (now you can refer to the straightforward question part):

```
var evens = arr[i].split("").filter(isEven); //works
var odds = arr[i].split("").filter(!isEven); // doesn't work
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to do this would be to just pass an anonymous function which returns the negated result of `isEven`.

```
var evens = arr[i].split("").filter(function(el, index, array) {
  return !isEven(el, index, array);
});
```

But you could take this a step further and write a `not` function which essentially generates the anonymous function for you. Here's an example of such a function.

```js
var input = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
function isEven(value) {
  return value % 2 === 0;
}
function not(f) {
  return function() {
    return !f.apply(null, arguments);
  }
}

var output = input.filter(not(isEven));
console.log(output);
```

If you're in an environment that supports [rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) then you could write your `not` function like this.

```js
var input = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
function isEven(value) {
  return value % 2 === 0;
}
function not(f) {
  return function(...args) {
    return !f.apply(null, args);
  }
}

var output = input.filter(not(isEven));
console.log(output);
```

Comment: thanks! I like that `function not(f)` a lot, it's pretty clever, is that something often used?

Comment: @randomguy04 In functional programming, that general idea is used a lot. It's known as [composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition_(computer_science)) and is really handy for manipulating datasets, just like what you're doing here.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to pass in an anonymous function and then negate `isEven` in there:

```
var odds = arr[i].split("").filter(function(a, index, array) {
  return !isEven(a, index, array);
});
```

Simple Example:

[Working Example](https://jsbin.com/dabazed/1/edit?js,console)

```
function isEven(n) {
  return n % 2 === 0;
}

var arr = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];

var a = arr.filter(isEven);

var b = arr.filter(function(a) {
  return !isEven(a);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution I use is something like this:

```js
var numbers = [0,1,2,3,4,5];
var evens = [];
var odds = [];

function isEvenOrNot(getEven) {
    return function(num) {
        if (num % 2 == 0 || num == 0){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}

evens = numbers.filter(isEvenOrNot(true));
odds = numbers.filter(isEvenOrNot(false));

console.log(evens); // [0,2,4]
console.log(odds); // [1,3,5]
```